# Cache Memory Confusion

Tags: cpu-cache

Can CPU Cache still be utilized for memory use by the programmer while it is operating in the UC mode? Or is this impossible because the programmer is unable to address Cache memory? I mistakenly thought MTRR's could be used to address CPU Cache memory?

Comment: What does this have to do with databases?

Comment: Their are applications now running in memory like SAP Hana? Just trying to get a hold on how much access a programmer has to ALL the memory on the machine including CPU Cache. I have been reading some interesting White Papers, (maybe a little futuristic), about using CPU memory to link to Data Bases stored in RAM. It sounded futuristic as mentioned above, but interesting. There was dependance on CPU memory speed to make a in-memory data base execute at a new level. That's the connection between the two.

Comment: Hmm, you should probably tag the question with things that are directly related to the question topic, rather than things that aren't mentioned at all in the question.  For a start, you'll get better replies (if you tag it with e.g. "cache" then people who know about caches will see it).

Comment: I tried adding "cache" as a tag but it didn't take. Thanks. I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be asking if you can turn off the normal behavior of cache and instead use its SRAM as a directly addressable memory area.  The short answer is no.  Also, Uncacheable (UC) is a property of a memory page or memory region, not a mode of the cache itself.

Comment: Thank you. That's the question I meant to ask. Do you have a work around? And why wouldn't they leave Cache addressable to programmers, in a mode if we want to use it our way, fine. If we want to use it their way, fine, we don't change anything. There are many penalties that can take place if you use it their way, programmers should have the option to use that potential addressable memory for their best use. Thanks again, you posed the question perfectly.

Comment: The reason processors don't support this mode is that cache is vital to the performance of the CPU.  Disabling cache means every single access goes all the way to DRAM.  Windows might boot in about a week.  Only in small embedded systems do you find processors attached to a cacheless memory substem.

Comment: Micro-code must be what prevents the access and addressability, but it seems that it should be the option of the programmer to use Cache their way. Cache can present a lot of negative scenarios when in use. Our operating system doesn't use paging, so there is really no need for use of any Cache layer.It seems a waste, fast memory sitting there unused. We could program it our way and put it to better use. I think this feature may change one day, because we can't be the only ones that wishes Cache was addressable. These Caches are getting large, it would be nice to store data our way to benefit.

Comment: Microcode is not the problem at all.  Instead of jumping to wild conclusions, search online for information about cache architecture.  The first thing you'll notice is that cache uses different physical structures and organization than normal addressable SRAM.

Comment: @srKing...can you be more specific about my search? I did search. I also finally found the thread that addressed my original question. Some person believed that the Bare Metal OS had the capability of storing data in Cache. We felt that Intel (in our case) didn't want programmers utilizing Cache in their way. Basically locked out. Some of these Cache sizes are getting rather large, and are code is in our own language which is quite small. As mentioned before we don't utilize memory the traditional way. It would be very advantageous to us if say Intel provided cache to us but let us program it.